# How to add Twitter Expanded Tweets? (was: twitter media preview card for my site?)

Tags: twitter, mashup

I googled a lot about how to make twitter media preview for my website entities if they are linked in a tweet like images below:

[image: YouTube example]

[image: Kickstarter example]

Any idea where can I find some documentation about it? Or a tutorial? Is this possible or these media/site previews are hardcoded in twitter?

---

**EDIT:**

so, what I need: 
If someone links my site on twitter, my widget appear under the tweet, like below:

[image: Example example]

---

**UPDATE 2012-06-13**

It appears this is an [Expanded Tweet](http://blog.twitter.com/2012/06/experience-more-with-expanded-tweets.html) - -what the requirements are to integrate these expansions into Twitter are do not appear to be displayed - but this sure is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope your in luck. They're not hardcoded into Twitter, they're available in the JSON response. You actually have in your post the word you need to google for `entities`.

You can add `include_entities=1` to the end of most REST api calls and it will give you expanded information about the URL's contained within the JSON. It will split out all the URL's where you can parse out the Youtube links for example. The JSON also includes a special `media_url` entity but it only works for pictures. In any case, you can still parse out the media easily like youtube with a regex match because you get the URL's split out nicely with this `include_entities=1` parameter.

example call :

[http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&**include_entities=1**](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&%2a%2ainclude_entities=1%2a%2a)

more documentation : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

**answer edited below based on clarification:**

Editing Twitter itself with previews is impossible and it's also ineffective. 75% of traffic to Twitter happens outside of Twitter.com. However the most probable solution to achieving this request would be to download a browser extension.

This extension for example enbales previews of webpages directly in the users stream content preview pane on Twitter.com

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oijgblonhcagdhfbgjilnpjipmijimmn

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I need the opposite what you explained... I edited the question. I want to provide a preview widget for MY site entities...

Comment: oh you want to edit Twitter itself? This is impossible. Also, if it were possible (it's not) but I'm not sure how effective it would be because most traffic to Twitter happens outside of the website. The closest you can get to this if you and your users downloaded a browser extension.

Comment: No I don't want to edit twitter. I just wondered that is there any chance to provide page or media previews like Kikstarter or yt do. I agree that I can't do this now. Maybe In future... I just wanted to know that I don't missed anything... Anyway thanks for your respond.

Comment: nope you could only do that for photos using the photo uploading API or be one of twitters content partners.

Comment: Very interesting. They're calling this "Expanded Tweets" http://blog.twitter.com/2012/06/experience-more-with-expanded-tweets.html - very interesting development. I've added a link to their announcement into the question.